# Adding element to array of array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, colors

I have an array of arrays with color variable

```
Color [] [] bin = new Color [64] [];
```

afterwards I want to insert colors into this array
Im looping through a list of colors and tmpColor is the particular color in the loop. I need to insert it into the specific loop it belongs.

```
int idx = 16* (tmpColor.getRed()/64) + 4*(tmpColor.getGreen()/64) + (tmpColor.getBlue()/64);
bin[idx].push(tmpColor);
```

However this doesn't seem to work. How do I add a color into the array in the specific index?

Comment: The response "doesn't seem to work" is extremely vague. Do you get an error? If you do, post it. Do you get an exception? If you do, post the stack trace. Can `idx` exceed 64? There are some mistakes in your code, but I'd like to help you hunt them down rather than just give you the answer.

Comment: max idx is 16 * 3 + 4 * 3 + 3 = 63 - all is ok here.

Comment: This is the error i get ´Cannot invoke push(Color) on the array type Color[]´ idx cant exceed 64

Comment: Why do you think that there is a `#push` method to add something to an array? This is *Java* and not *JavaScript*. If you want to add something use `bin[index] = arrayOfColorToAdd;`. Mind that `tmpColor` is not an array and can't be added to `bin[index]`.

Comment: @user3540466 are you just calculating one number and want to store it in the array, or are there some follow up values that might to be stored inside the first Dimension of the array, which would validate using a two dimensional array.

Comment: Do you really need a matrix? What kind of information do you have to store? e.g. do you have a value for both `bin[0][0]` AND `bin[0][1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solve it is the following: instead of creating an array of arrays I created and array of ArrayLists

```
int size = 64;
ArrayList<Color>[] lists = new ArrayList[size];
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    lists[i] = new ArrayList<Color>();
}
```

After that I pushed the elements to their particular bin ( in this case in lists)

```
lists[idx].add(tmpColor);
```

Afterwards getting the lenght and the first color in the array is s follows:

```
for (ArrayList<Color> p : lists){
    System.out.println("size of bin" + p.size());
    if (p.isEmpty())
        continue;
    else {
    System.out.println("list" + p.get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd have suggested as well. It's simple and satisfies all your requirements. Good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `List` of colors for your index you can use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
private Map<Integer, List<Color>> bin = new HashMap<Integer, List<Color>>();

int idx = 16* (tmpColor.getRed()/64) + 4*(tmpColor.getGreen()/64) + (tmpColor.getBlue()/64);

if(bin.get(idx)==null) bin.put(idx, new ArrayList<Color>());

bin.get(idx).add(tmpColor); //This should be exactly what you need
```

You can use also different structures like `List<List<Color>>` or `List<Color>[]`. Every structure relays on a `List` since `List` can be updated and created without knowing the initial length.

What I would do is create a separate class for color bin and some useful methods within:

```
public class Bin{

    private List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

    public void addColor(Color col){
        this.colors.add(col);
    }

    public List<Color> getColors(){
        return this.colors;
    }

    public boolean hasColor(Color col){
        return colors.contains(col);
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

And the best structure for your goal now is a map with lazy initialization:

```
private Map<Integer, Bin> myBinsOfColors = new HashMap<Integer, Bin>();

int idx = 16* (tmpColor.getRed()/64) + 4*(tmpColor.getGreen()/64) + (tmpColor.getBlue()/64);

if(myBinsOfColors.get(idx)==null) myBinsOfColors.put(idx, new Bin()); //Lazy

myBinsOfColors.get(idx).addColor(tmpColor); //This should be exactly what you need
```

To get the avarage and the number of colors you can implement two methods in the `Bin` class:

```
public class Bin{

    private List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

    //As above.
    public Color calculateAverage() {
       Integer red = 0;
       Integer blue = 0;
       Integer green = 0;
       if(!colors.isEmpty()) {
         for (Color col : colors) {
            red+= col.getRed();
            green+= col.getGreen();
            blue+= col.getBlue();
         }

         return new Color(red/colors.size(), green/colors.size(), blue/colors.size());
       }
       return null;
    }

    public int getColorCount(){
        return this.colors.size();
    }

    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: What I have is  an array of colors, then I want to classify them in different bins (64 to be precise). Afterwards Ill make a hash map that has the average color of each bin and the count of how many colors are in that bin.